# How do I convert multiple columns to a single column?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Col1        Col2        Col3        Col4
a       b       c       d
e       f       g       h
```

I need to convert it to this:

```
Col1        New
a       b
a       c
a       d
e       f
e       g
e       h
```

I have a ton of data and doing this by hand is out of the question. Does anyone know of a fast way to do this? I'm hoping that there is a built in way (such as paste->transpose or a function?). If not could someone point me at a relevant VBA example since I am little rusty at VBA.

Comment: As a partial answer (since by VBA is certainly rustier than yours, look towards concatenation.

Comment: hmm I think that is just as much work (if not more) as looping over everything. Unless I am mistaken =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the data you want to transform (not including column headings) and run the following macro.

```
Sub Transform()

    Dim targetRowNumber As Long
    targetRowNumber = Selection.Rows(Selection.Rows.Count).Row + 2

    Dim col1 As Variant
    Dim cell As Range

    Dim sourceRow As Range: For Each sourceRow In Selection.Rows

        col1 = sourceRow.Cells(1).Value
        For Each cell In sourceRow.Cells

            If Not cell.Column = Selection.Column Then
                Selection.Worksheet.Cells(targetRowNumber, 1) = col1
                Selection.Worksheet.Cells(targetRowNumber, 2) = cell.Value
                targetRowNumber = targetRowNumber + 1
            End If

        Next cell

    Next sourceRow

End Sub
```

Comment: I really hope you didn't just write that on my behalf. However, "THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I NEEDED"! Thanks =)